# Laravel 4 how to pass URI Parameters to Model function

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this route, want to pass the `uri` parameters in Laravel:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'view/'), function(){
    Route::get('news/listings/{limLow}/{limTop}', function() {
                return Model::Foo($limLow, $limTop);
            });
});
```

In my Foo function `Foo(param1=null, param2=null){}` the variables param1 and 2 are `null`, as if no variable assigned to the parameters event though an url of something like `view/news/listings/1/10` is requested.

My usual approach is go through a `controller` first, pass the uri variable in the controller, then go to the `model`, but I'm trying a direct approach here, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'view/'), function(){
    Route::get('news/listings/{limLow}/{limTop}', function($limlow, $limTop) {
                return Model::Foo($limLow, $limTop);
            });
});
```

When passing parameters to a route, those parameters should be set ass variables in function or method used in route. See more info at http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing